# Singleton class, multidimensional array unset element

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, unset

I am trying to remove irrelevant data from a multidimensional array.

The array is looking like this:

```
[6] => Array
    (
        [710C27E0-822A-4513-9D44-D97E929484A9] => Array
            (
                [documents] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => error message
                    )

            )

    )
```

And i am using the following code:

```
<?php
class report {
private static $instance;
private $data = array();

private function __construct() { }

private function __clone() { }

public function __destruct() { }

public static function singleton() {
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
        self::$instance = new self();

    return self::$instance;
}

public function check() {
    foreach($this->data as $key => &$values) {
        foreach($values as $k => &$value) {
            /* some checks */

            if($return != null)
                $values[$return] = $values[$k];

            unset($values[$k]);
        }
        if(sizeof($values) == 0)
            unset($this->data[$key];
    }
}

public function __toString() {
    print_r($this->data);
    return '';
}
}
```

When i replace upper check function by the following code it is working, but i am looking for some better/cleaner and especially faster solution.

```
public function check() {
    $_data = json_encode($this->data);
    $data = json_decode($_data);

    foreach($data as $key => &$values) {
        foreach($values as $k => &$value) {
            /* some checks */
            if($return != null)
                $values->$return = $values->$k;

            unset($values->$k);
        }
    }
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

**SOLVED** but not understanding it..

```
public function log($id, $guid, $job, $message) {
    $this->data[$id][$guid][$job][] = $message;
}
```

when i var_dump($guid) it returns:

```
string(36) "710C27E0-822A-4513-9D44-D97E929484A9"
```

now i did a string cast:

```
var_dump((string)$guid);
```

returning:

```
string(36) "710C27E0-822A-4513-9D44-D97E929484A9"
```

but

```
$this->data[$id][(string)$guid][$job][] = $message;
```

works!

Comment: Value/purpose of `$return`?

Comment: $return is a guid and is coming from a other database.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's coming from anywhere and will always be `null`.

Comment: I didn't add that code... thats not where the problem is. The problem is that unset($values[$k]) isn't working..

Comment: Try `unset($this->data[$key][$k])`

Comment: Already tried, not working.
Also tried without pass by reference, not working.

Comment: Solved.. see orignal post.